# How to get file name while creating snippets (Live Templates)

Tags: webstorm

I am creating a snippet for my templates in Meteor and the only thing left to be perfect would be to know the file name in which that snippet was called.

What I have:

```
type: temp + tab
```

What I get:

```
 <template name="">

 </template>
```

What I want:

```
 <template name="">
   file_name.html
 </template>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-live-templates.html) is how "snippets" are called in WebStorm and other IDEA-based IDEs.

There is `filename()` function *(`fileNameWithoutExtension()` has been added a few version later)* that can provide such info/text for a variable. [Official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions).

Knowing that: add a variable into your template and then use the aforementioned function on it:

```html
<template name="$END$">
    $FILE$
</template>
```

Now click on **"Edit Variables"** button and use it there. Selecting "Skip if defined" will make that variable "non-editable" during template expansion.

[image]

Comment: You can use `fileNameWithoutExtension()` function for only getting the name of the file and you have add this to the `Default value` section not into `Expression`

Comment: @VeRJiL 1) `fileNameWithoutExtension()` was not available back in 2014... plus the author did not state that he wants "file name part only". 2) `Expression` is the right place. `Default value` is for fallback. In any case -- in this particular case the final result will be the same regardless where the function was entered.